# Dynamic reference to files and classes in PHP regardless of the main folder path

Tags: php, dynamic, path, reference, content-management-system

I'm working on a custom CMS in PHP and I currently have a file structure like this

```
includes/autoload.php
index.php
```

In my `index.php` file I reference an autoload class which autoloads all my other classes. This line would be on the top of all my files. I currently reference it using the code below

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/autoload.php');
```

This would only work if the custom CMS is installed in the root folder of the website (public_html)*.* But I'm looking to make it more dynamic, so the CMS can also be installed in a subfolder of the website like `public_html/someCMS/` . So then the require would have to be.

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/someCMS/includes/autload.php'
```

Now I'm thinking to accomplish this I could use something like

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $install_path . '/includes/autload.php'
```

But then I would want the `$install_path` somewhere in a settings like file, so it's in one place and easy to change. Does anyone know how this is accomplished? Or maybe how wordpress or any other CMS do this?

My best bet would be to make a settings file, which would always be placed in the root of the website, which has the install path

```
<?php
$install_path = '/someCMS';
?>
```

And then reference it in my `index.php`  and other files like

```
<?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/settings.php');
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$install_path.'/includes/autoload.php');
?>
```

But I feel that this is not the best way to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

If you know the location of your autoload.php relative to your index.php won't change (and from your question, it shouldn't, in this case), using the magic **DIR** constant and appending the relative path would probably be easiest and not require any more configuration.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php

That gives you the directory of the file it's used in, so you could do

```
<?php
require(__DIR__.'/includes/autoload.php');
?>
```

Comment: Eventually I also would have files in a subfolder like `/admin/index.php`. Then having `__DIR__ . '/includes/autoload.php'` would not work anymore because it would look for the file from the subfolder, while it would need to look from the root inwards